# AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.media.RemoteController$OnClientUpdateListener.onClientSessionEvent

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I'm getting a bizarre crash in production on my Android app on three specific Samsung models.  It's complaining that I don't override an abstract method `onNewSessionEvent`, which does not exist in the standard Android platform:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener.html

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.media.RemoteController$OnClientUpdateListener.onClientSessionEvent(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)"
   at android.media.RemoteController.onNewSessionEvent(RemoteController.java:1208)
   at android.media.RemoteController.access$1000(RemoteController.java:61)
   at android.media.RemoteController$MediaControllerCallback.onSessionEvent(RemoteController.java:851)
   at android.media.session.MediaController$MessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaController.java:1073)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The three models are the Galaxy S5 (AT&T and Sprint) and S6 Edge (T-mobile), all on 5.x.  I don't have these devices so of course I can't reproduce and troubleshoot locally.

My code does use an `OnClientUpdateListener` registered on a `RemoteController`, but that's as far as this makes sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [RemoteController source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/RemoteController.java#692), AOSP's `MediaControllerCallback` (used to provide backward compatibility between the new media session APIs added in Lollipop with the deprecated `RemoteController`) only implements [onPlaybackStateChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html#onPlaybackStateChanged(android.media.session.PlaybackState)) and [onMetadataChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html#onMetadataChanged(android.media.MediaMetadata)).

It seems that on those devices, the API has been silently 'augmented' with attempting to handle [onSessionEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html#onSessionEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) as well. Unfortunately, one downside of interfaces is that all methods must be implemented so adding new APIs often breaks existing implementations (see [ComponentCallbacks2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html) for an example).

If you want to continue to use `RemoteController. OnClientUpdateListener` on these Lollipop devices the solution is obvious: implement the method. You now know what the method signature is, so implementing the method (with an empty body) would remove this error message. You may certainly run into additional errors if there are additional methods they expect your `OnClientUpdateListener` to have (there are quite a few additional ones in [MediaController.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html) that are not reflected in the public APIs in `OnClientUpdateListener`). I'd strongly recommend finding a real device to test your updated `OnClientUpdateListener` before publishing the app again.

An alternate solution is to use two separate [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)s - one for KitKat alone (and would implement `OnClientUpdateListener`) and a separate one for Lollipop and above that would not. This would allow you to use the [Lollipop media playback control APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#MediaPlaybackControl) and [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html) APIs on Lollipop and above (by reading the `Token` from [EXTRA_MEDIA_SESSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#EXTRA_MEDIA_SESSION)) while maintaining KitKat compatibility.

Comment: Luckily, adding this one method solved the error.  But we were never able to reproduce in the office, even with a phone that was the same model number as one of the crash reports. :/

Comment: How to add this method. I was trying extend OnClientUpdateListener and add in extended interface but have the same exeption. Could you write how to do that properly?

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski - just add the method to your Listener `public void onClientSessionEvent(String string, Bundle bundle) { }`

Comment: Yeah, but how exactly? If I make new interface like below I have error "Missing permission to control media" and with extended interface with that method have still that problem. 

        RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener myListener = new RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener() {
        
        public void onClientSessionEvent(String string, Bundle bundle) { }
              (Overrided methods)
                }

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski - A missing permission issue has absolutely nothing to do with this problem. I'd create a new question with your code

Comment: Ok. Here is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635852/abstractmethoderror-onclientsessionevent-and-missing-permission-to-control-medi